# Text layout issue with div inside of annother div with a fixed width

Tags: css

I have a div.one which has a fixed size and a background color. Within it is another div which starts off hidden but is shown with javascript in certain circumstances.

How can I make it so when div.two is shown, you can see its background color and the text doesn't wrap? Basically I want it to behave like it doesn't have a containing div with a fixed size. Is this possible? Thanks

```
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    Some Text
  </div>
</div>

.one {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}
.two {
  background-color: grey;
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/1979063)

```
.two {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: grey;
    white-space:nowrap;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix the dimension of the div as well to 20px and 20px, and set the `white-spacing` to `nowrap`.

```
.two {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  ...
}
```

Check out [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/hKazb/1/) to see if I solved your question.

Comment: [`text-wrap`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-wrap.asp) is not supported in any modern browser.